# How can I find this pattern in a text document?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

So im practicing some RegEx in python and essentially I want to look through a log of transaction numbers and see if any of them are returning an error such as Error in phone Activation.

I was successful in searching in a dictionary for something that starts with Error and then ends with Activation, so that if it was tablet, watch, etc , it would still find the error. However, as a bulk text file, it will not successfully find the pattern.

So the code I used to find it in a dictionary was such that the dictionary key was a transaction number and the error (or lack thereof) was the value:

```
    for i in Transaction_Log:
        if bool(re.search("^Error.* Activation$", Transaction_Log[i])):  
            print("Found requested error in transaction number " + i)
            error_count += 1
```

This works, however using the same search function cant find anything when in a text file setup like this:

```
    Transnum: 20190510001 error: Error in phone Activation,
    Transnum: 20190510002 error: none,
    Transnum: 20190510003 error: Error in tablet Activation,
```

Ideally, it can find the type of errors, and when successful I can make a counter to see how many there are, however my boolean statement is not True when searching this way through a text file.

Searching for just the word Error does work though.

Comment: `^` and `$` are anchor points for the beginning and end of the input string, so if the input starts with `Transnum` then the `^` is going to prevent a match.

Comment: @CAustin, Gotcha. I thought that was only for match and not search. hmmm. Any ideas on how I could find a string starting with Error and ending in Activation anywhere in the line?

Comment: Sure, if the substring you're looking for always starts with `Error`, and if there's never an instance of `Error` earlier in the input, you can simply remove the `^` and it should work.

Comment: @CAustin hmmm. Still doesn't seem to work but that makes sense what you said about the anchors. Ill play around with that

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that each line ends with a comma, so that would be messing up the `$` anchor at the end as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @CAustin, I figured out that I was searching for the wrong pattern due to the line not starting with error and the ending of the line also having a comma at the end. By removing both anchors, I was able to find what I needed to find in this example, so for anyone else looking for something similar it was this...

```
    for line in testingDoc:
        if bool(re.search("Error.* Activation", line)):
            print("found error in transaction")
```